# PHP 7.1 flush doesn't work at all

Tags: php, flush, php-7.1

I need to flush content during the script is running. Sounds simple yet there are several discussions about that issue. I've tried everything I was able to find so I thing there has to be something wrong with server. Perhaps some bad conf. I'm able to change server conf if you tell me what to look for.

So far I checked output_buffering (512), output_handler (no value), zlib.output_compression (Off), zlib.output_handler (no value). The server runs plain Apache without fast-cgi or so.

No matter what is the size of flushed string, it does nothing until the script finishes - then everything is rendered together.

I post a sample of my final code but I've tried every code sample I've found online.

```
// Turn off apache-level compression
@apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);

// Turn off compression
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);

session_write_close();

while (ob_get_level()) ob_end_flush();

header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header("Content-Encoding: identity", true);

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){

    ob_start(null,4096,PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_FLUSHABLE);
    echo "$i";
    echo str_repeat(' ',4096);
    usleep(250000);
    ob_end_flush();
    flush();

}
```

I began in cakephp 3.5 action but when I wasn't able to get it work I extracted the code to separate .php file and I'm accessing the file directly. Network control suggests that it's not problem of browser caching.

Thank you for every hint.

**EDIT:**
After hours of work I've figured out that it was an antivirus issue. And since almost every antivirus checks webcontent even with SSL these days, I guess there is no guaranteed way to pass partial/chunked content to the user.

Comment: It is possible that the web browser does not support partial content in the way that you want. The browser could be buffering your output into its own cache and waiting for the entire transfer to finish before showing anything.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus According to what I've found, if the browser caches output, it doesn't render it but you can see things happening in Network control. But when I send the request to server the Network control shows nothing until the script finishes and then it shows this:
Request sent 64 μs | Waiting (TTFB) 3.40 s | Content Download 17.97 ms
So I believe it's not browser caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be more clear a enter the result as an answer:
After hours of work I've figured out that it was an antivirus issue. And since almost every antivirus checks webcontent even with SSL these days, I guess there is no guaranteed way to pass partial/chunked content to the user.